# Can I make An App Which Uses Data From Other Apps?

Tags: copyright, software

Google Hangouts is closing down soon and I want to make a messaging app which lets you import your Hangouts conversations into it via Google Takeout. I'm not sure if this is legal though, since Google Hangouts is a trademark. I'm not making money off their app, because I won't charge users for use nor place ads. But something about this feels like it would violate some sort of law. Keep in mind that Hangouts is closing anyways, and this is just a source of redemption. I'm not going about any sneaky business to get to your Hangouts message information, since Google lets you download it directly through Google Takeout. Is this legal? Do I have to sign some sort of agreement with Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't selling anything, nor advertising, and you make it clear that you are in no way affiliated with, nor sponsored or endorsed by Google, then there is no trademark issue. Be sure nbot to use "Hangouts" as the name of your app, just to be safe,  but you can say "works with Google hangouts data" or something descriptive of he sort, provided that this is accurate.

You aren't copying anything, so there would seem to be no copyright issue. You would need to comply with the Google hangout an Google API terms of Service, but I don't see anything in those prohibiting the sort of app described in the question. I see no obvious legal problems here.

Note this is general and generic information on the law, not legal advice. I am not a lawyer, and I am absolutely not **your** lawyer.